# Why is the neutrino oscillation probability formula independent of the Majorana phases?

Tags: neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

Is there a simple way to understand why the neutrino oscillation probability formula is independent of the Majorana phases?

Comment: The PMNS matrix certainly contains CP-violating Majorana phases in principle. Are you asking why measuring them is very hard, or some odd question of principle?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Of course, the PMNS matrix depends on the Majorana phases. I did not doubt that. My question was _why is the oscillation probability independent of the Majorana phases_?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Isn't it true that oscillation probability formulae _do not contain_ of the Majorana phases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean the routine formula, for Greek flavor indices and Latin mass eigenstate indices,
$$
P_{\alpha\rightarrow\beta}=\left|\left\langle \nu_\beta(t)|\nu_\alpha\right\rangle \right|^2=\left|\sum_i U_{\alpha i}^{*}U_{\beta i}e^{ -i m_i^2 L/2E }\right|^2.
$$

Now the standard result of [Bilenky et al 1980](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(80)90927-2) extends the PMNS matrix to 
$$
U\mapsto U P,
$$
where $P\equiv \operatorname {diag}(1,\exp (i\alpha_{21}/2), \exp(i\alpha_{31}/2))$. One *calls* these two *α*s Majorana phases, all the remaining phases of the diagonalized Majorana masses having been absorbed into the conventional-looking "CP-phase" in *U*. It's just a name.

Now, for this formula, visibly, the sum over *i* involves, for each *i* respective factors of  $\exp(-i\alpha_i + -im_i^2 L/2E+i\alpha_i)$, involving
P* , *P*, and the propagator term. But the respective P* and *P* terms in the exponents of this diagonal cancel each other, and, presto!, the propagator is not modified, $=\exp(-im_i^2 L/2E)$, and all trace of the two Majorana phases is gone *in this particular formula*.

Note this is predicated on the highly restricted and peculiar nature of "conventional" neutrino oscillation experiments, that cannot measure real Majorana processes, violating lepton number, $\Delta L=2$, like neutrinoless double β decay --experiments which can do that, like CUORE, can also, in principle, access these extra phases, but are still languishing empty-handed. Bilenky et al, in 1980, also fantasize about possible right-handed extra interactions, etc... that might allow access to these phases in oscillation experiments.